# Solve $\pi(xn)=\frac{xn}{\frac{n}{\pi(n)}+\ln(x)}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics

> Solve $$\pi(xn)=\frac{xn}{\frac{n}{\pi(n)}+\ln(x)}.$$

By the prime number theorem, we have:
$$\pi(n)\sim\frac{n}{\ln(n)}$$

Therefore: 
$$\pi(xy)\sim\frac{xy}{\ln(xy)}$$
$$\pi(xy)\sim\frac{xy}{\ln(x)+\ln(y)}$$
$$\frac{xy}{\pi(xy)}\sim \ln(x)+\ln(y)$$
$$\frac{xy}{\pi(xy)}-\ln(x)\sim \ln(y)$$
$$\frac{y}{\frac{xy}{\pi(xy)}-\ln(x)}\sim\frac{y}{\ln(y)}$$
$$\frac{y}{\frac{xy}{\pi(xy)}-\ln(x)}\sim\pi(y)$$
$$\pi(xy)\sim\frac{xy}{\frac{y}{\pi(y)}+\ln(x)}$$
We get an asymptotic relation between $\pi(xy)$ and $\pi(y)$. Now since the prime counting function is defined on $\mathbb {R}$, how can I find, for any integer $n$, the value $x$ such that:
$$\pi(xn)=\frac{xn}{\frac{n}{\pi(n)}+\ln(x)}$$

Comment: Technically this asymptotic result doesn't imply that such a solution exists at all. Moreover one cannot in general do all of this arithmetic while still preserving asymptotic relationships (specifically the subtraction can cause problems).

Comment: I understand, but i found some solutions for x using brute force approach, so i'm looking for a more efficient calculation method in order to satisfy my curiosity!

Comment: Also, it could probably fail if the difference between $x$ and $n$ is too big, but even with all of this arithmetic, these kind of asymptotic relations are always fairly accurate, because we use a real value of $\pi(n)$ as an input.

Comment: Just out of curioisity : could you show a few of the solutions you obtained using  the brute force approach ? I am totally stuck.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici of course, i'll post more later when i get to the office, but here's an example: n = 32, x = 2.1937227078504

Comment: n=23, x=1.967498085

Comment: n=127, x=2.731598005922

Answer (score 1):

*This is too long for a comment.*

Having problems with $\pi(xn)$ when $x$ is a real, nevertheless, I considered looking to the zero's of  function
$$f(x)=\pi ( n x)-\frac{n x}{\frac{n}{\pi (n)}+\log (x)}$$ which was accepted by a CAS.

For $n=23$, the first roots of $f(x)=0$ with $x>1$ are $1.343$, $1.378$, $1.865$, $1.966$, $2.043$, $2.167$, $2.380$, $2.565$, $2.593$, $2.652$ and so on; the last I found being $4.390$.

This makes a bunch of solutions.

Comment: this is ok, but as i explained in my answer, the problem is that the $\pi(nx)$ part only keeps the integer part of $nx$... In my example, $n=50$, i can also find a value for $x$ such that $\frac{xn}{\frac{n}{\pi(n)}+\ln(x)}=20,21,22...$, but the problem is that there is no solution for $\pi (nx)=\frac{xn}{\frac{n}{\pi(n)}+\ln(x)}=20,21,22...$

Comment: How do you find the roots for n=23 ? I'll wait a couple hours before accepting the answer, it looks good, but its still unclear which value for $\pi(nx)$ we can use... I can use the product log function with $\pi(nx)=20$, which gives me another solution: $n=50, x = 1.4938$, and therefore $\frac{50*1.4938}{\frac{50}{\pi (50)}+\log (1.4938)}=20$ but the problem is that $\pi (50*1.4938)=21$

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé. Just plotting and zooming ! Tedious isn't it ? For some values, for the roots which do not corresponds to vertical parts, Newton method works. For example, $1.3742733744612158480$, $1.9674980859237738122$ (you gave it), $2.1727492562494974508$, $2.3813819233304656853$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the question did not mention it, but there is the solution x=1, for any n. Now let's take n=50. The first solution is $n=50$, $x=1$:
$$\pi(50)=\frac{50}{\frac{50}{\pi(50)}+\ln(1)}=15$$
Now as x grows, we will also get:
$$\pi(50*\frac{53}{50})=\frac{50*\frac{53}{50}}{\frac{50}{\pi(50)}+\ln(\frac{53}{50})}\approx16$$
$$\pi(50*\frac{59}{50})=\frac{50*\frac{59}{50}}{\frac{50}{\pi(50)}+\ln(\frac{59}{50})}\approx17$$
$$\pi(50*\frac{61}{50})=\frac{50*\frac{61}{50}}{\frac{50}{\pi(50)}+\ln(\frac{61}{50})}\approx18$$
$$\pi(50*\frac{67}{50})=\frac{50*\frac{67}{50}}{\frac{50}{\pi(50)}+\ln(\frac{67}{50})}\approx19$$
After that, it will not be possible because: 
$$\pi(xn)-\frac{xn}{\frac{n}{\pi(n)}+\ln(x)}>1$$
And this difference will grow as x grows.

So now we can find x for $\pi(xn)=16,17,18,19$ using the product log function:
$$ x=\frac{-16W\left(-\frac{ne^{-\frac{n}{\pi(n)}}}{16}\right)}{n} $$
$$ x=\frac{-17W\left(-\frac{ne^{-\frac{n}{\pi(n)}}}{17}\right)}{n} $$
$$ x=\frac{-18W\left(-\frac{ne^{-\frac{n}{\pi(n)}}}{18}\right)}{n} $$
$$ x=\frac{-19W\left(-\frac{ne^{-\frac{n}{\pi(n)}}}{19}\right)}{n} $$
[(from Wolfram Alpha)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bb%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bc%7D%5Cln(x)-x%3D0)

Finally, we get the following solutions:
$$n=50,x=1$$
$$n=50,x=1.096...$$
$$n=50,x=1.19347...$$
$$n=50,x=1.29232...$$
$$n=50,x=1.39248...$$

Comment: $x$ on both sides ?

Comment: no, sorry, i was not clear, $\pi(xn)$ is replaced with 16,17,18,19